# Bold, font size - Hyperlink

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

Can I change the font size and make the font bold in this fragment of code in RMarkdown? I export this report to PDF.

```
\newcommand{\soln}{https://www.google.com/}

\begin{center}

\href{\soln}{`r df['name']`}

\end{center}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use latex command `\bfseries` to bold the text and then wrap the whole `\href` command within a font size command, for example, `\huge`. [see here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes%2C_families%2C_and_styles#Reference_guide) for the list of font-size changing commands.

````
---
title: "large and bold hyperlink"
output: pdf_document
date: "2022-12-01"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

df <- "Whatever"
```

\newcommand{\soln}{https://www.google.com/}

\begin{center}

\huge{\href{\soln}{\bfseries `r paste(df)`}}

\end{center}
````